# Disable automatically changing object value in java linkedlist

Tags: java, linked-list

I just notice strange behavior today, even when I've been writing in Java for 2 year.
Here take a look at my code,

```
    public static void main() {
    Lorem lo = new Lorem("abc", 2);        
    LinkedList<Lorem> lim = new LinkedList<>();        
    lim.add(lo);
    LinkedList<Lorem> lid = new LinkedList<>();        
    lo.tf++;        
    lid.add(lo);

    System.out.println("in list lim: " + lim.get(0).term + " " + lim.get(0).tf);        
    System.out.println("in list lid: " + lid.get(0).term + " " + lid.get(0).tf);
    }

    class Lorem {
    public String term;
    public int tf;

    public Lorem(String term, int tf) {
        this.term = term;
        this.tf = tf;
    }
    }
```

result are like this :

```
in list lim: abc 3
in list lid: abc 3
```

And yes, thats same object, added to different list. One list saving object when it's state are term = "abc", tf = 2. And the other save when term = "abc" and tf = 3. And you can see, at the end, i'm printing value of each list.
Surprisingly, object lo in lim has exactly same value with lo in lid. Even when i'm not synchronize them.
My question is : Why Java automatically updating (sync) other list like this? How to disable that behaviour?

Comment: Yes, mutable objects are like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not surprising and I wonder how you didn't discover this in 2 years of programming.

Java works by references. So what you are storing in the list is not an object but a reference which points somewhere in the heap to the real allocated object, it's like if your `LinkedList` just contains a memory address to a Lorem somewhere.

Since you are adding the same reference to two lists, both references will point to the same `Lorem` instance (which is not technically contained in any of the two `LinkedList` since they just contain a reference to it).

If you want to store two different elements then you need to allocate a new object (and possibly copy/transfer the state).

Comment: you're right. maybe because I rarely or maybe never has case like this in information system development. Thanks for solution.